# Is gcc 4.8.2 correct in invoking the copy constructor in this defaulted default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Here's a simple, self-contained, non-compilable-on-gcc-4.8.2 example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
#include <atomic>

template <typename T>
class ValueParameter
{
public:
    ValueParameter() = default;

    ValueParameter(T initialValue) :
        _val(initialValue)
    {
    }

private:
    std::atomic<T> _val{T()};
};

ValueParameter<int> x;
```

I've compiled this successfully on several other gcc versions, including 5.3, but gcc 4.8.2 fails with the following error:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler11658-82-1cqz6ui/example.cpp: In constructor 'ValueParameter<T>::ValueParameter() [with T = int]':
7 : error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'
ValueParameter() = default;
^
In file included from /tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler11658-82-1cqz6ui/example.cpp:1:0:
```

[You can see the results online here](https://godbolt.org/g/EOOvSB).

I understand that `std::atomic<T>` is non-copyable, but it doesn't make any sense to me why the compiler would be trying to use the copy constructor within the default constructor. I did discover that changing the line:

```
    std::atomic<T> _val{T()};
```

to

```
    std::atomic<T> _val;
```

makes the file compile successfully. The uniform initialization was a relic from a previous version of the class that didn't have the constructor taking an initial value.

Should this be an error? Furthermore, what behavior *should* I expect in this case, where the member is initialized both inline to the class and within a constructor initializer list? I would like the default constructor to initialize `val` to `T()`, so I think I need the brace initializer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a gcc bug, and one that they've fixed by 4.9. At no point is your code invoking the copy constructor of `ValueParameter<T>` - so that member function should not be instantiated. Using a default member initializer for `atomic<T>` is fine - it is, indeed, constructible from a `T`.

> Furthermore, what behavior should I expect in this case, where the member is initialized both inline to the class and within a constructor initializer list?

Default member initializers are just that - defaults. If you provided an initializer in the mem-initializer-list (as you do in the `ValueParameter(T )` constructor), then the default is ignored. If you do not provide such an initializer (as you don't in `ValueParameter()`), then the default is used.

> I would like the default constructor to initialize val to `T()`, so I think I need the brace initializer there.

Your code should do precisely what you want it to do. gcc 4.8 just has a bug here.

Comment: IIRC C++11 was still technically "experimental" in gcc 4.8 anyways: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html